# Complex column-oriented table layout

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML+CSS grid layout as in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYhDo.png), which is essentially a column-oriented table (vs. the row-oriented HTML `<table>`, which is constructed row-by-row).

To achieve this layout, I have the backing grid constructed from `<div>`s, and the value groups as right-floating `<table>`s. Originally, I had the value groups as `<div>`s as well, but that requires fixed cell widths (esp. with cells spanning multiple columns), so now I'm using tables for the value groups. Either way though, I'm able to have a variable number of value groups, which I need.

What I'd like to do is use a `<table>` for the backing grid as well, so I can get all of the nice row-spanning and column-spanning for free. However, this has proven to be a difficult task, because the `table` element is treated as a single block in flow (elements cannot flow around it).

So my question is this: Could I possibly use a table for the "backing grid" in my layout, using only HTML + CSS? Also, feel free to suggest different approaches for the construction of this layout altogether.

**edit:**

I should have mentioned that this layout is to be generated dynamically, and it follows that single-table solution won't work. This is because, in this case, the items are static, but the value groups are not. I need to be able to easily add/remove value groups, so that this can be generated using a template engine such as [{{mustache}}](http://mustache.github.com/). With a single-table solution, in order to add a value group, every `<tr>` must have an additional set of `<td>`'s added, which is definitely non-trivial when using any templating engine, but especially with {{mustache}}, which is what I'm using.

For example, my source data (in JSON) might look like:

```
{
   "oneTwoTotal": "$0.00",
   "valueGroups":[
      {
         "groupName":"ValueGroup1",
         "values":[
            {
               "subgroupName":"Column 1",
               "item1":"$0.00",
               "item2":"$0.00",
               "item3":"$0.00",
               "total":"$0.00"
            },
            {
               "subgroupName":"Column 2",
               "item1":"$0.00",
               "item2":"$0.00",
               "item3":"$0.00",
               "total":"$0.00"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "groupName":"ValueGroup2",
         "values":[
            {
               "subgroupName":"Column 1",
               "item1":"$0.00",
               "item2":"$0.00",
               "item3":"$0.00",
               "total":"$0.00"
            },
            {
               "subgroupName":"Column 2",
               "item1":"$0.00",
               "item2":"$0.00",
               "item3":"$0.00",
               "total":"$0.00"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Imagine constructing the single-table solution with a templating engine, using this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing: http://fiddle.jshell.net/gGaXj/30/ . At the top level, I have a container `div`  with `position: relative`. Inside the container is a backing `table`, and another div with `position: absolute` with `right: 0; top: 0;` (positioned over the container) containing my right-floating value group tables. With this solution, I have the ease of using tables with rowspan/colspan, and the ease & speed of iterating over value-groups only once to add them to the layout. Plus, it's cross/legacy browser compatible, where a div + CSS table wouldn't be as much.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any `div`s. It can achieved using only the `table` element:

[Demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/2032478)

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">Really Complex Layout</th>
            <th colspan="2">Value Group 1</th>
            <th colspan="2">Value Group 2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 1</th>           
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>


    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4">One</td>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One Total</td>
            <td colspan="2">$0.00</td>
            <td colspan="2">$0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4">Two</td>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Two Total</td>
            <td colspan="2">$0.00</td>
            <td colspan="2">$0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">One & Two Total</td>
            <td colspan="2">$0.00</td>
            <td colspan="2">$0.00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can of course style it with CSS to make it look however you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was aware that this table could be generated using a single table with rowspans & colspans. The problem with that approach is generating such a table. I should have mentioned this in my original question; see the edit for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve that layout with a table, you need to use a combination of rowspan and colspan.

Heres a js fiddle [Table Layout](http://jsfiddle.net/rp3JX/1)

I've also put up an alternative layout that doesnt need to row span the items which would make it easier to change the number of items per set.

Update

never use mustache before looks useful. Your json only appears to have data for the One set from your image, this **[templated](http://jsfiddle.net/rp3JX/3/)** is pretty close.  I've put the rowspan for the item in its own row so that it doesnt interfere with the items.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was aware that this table could be generated using a single table with rowspans & colspans. The problem with that approach is generating such a table. I should have mentioned this in my original question; see the edit for further explanation.

Comment: Specifically, referring to the layout image, I need the ability to add/remove value groups easily, not items (items in this case are static). This is why I mentioned the table as being column-oriented, rather than row-oriented.

Comment: So, regarding the update, is this what you would do then? The template engine has to do an iteration over every value group, for every row. This would be slow for large amounts of data, but it does work. I'm not sure that this would be better than my original solution, where I have right-floated tables for value-groups, however your solution does let me use table `rowspan` & `colspan` for the backing grid, which is nice.

Comment: As I said I've never use mustache before, so not sure if thats is a good implementation or not.  You already have another method that works so I'd only swap if you could gain from a differnet solution, maintainability, performance etc. Bacause it only itterates over the value groups not sure it'll be any better, putting your item elements into an array might make the template easier but as for performance I wouldn't know.